Understanding Error Estimation in Agisoft Metashape for UAV Imagery
I'm currently analyzing UAV imagery from a recent survey for landslide research using Agisoft Metashape. During the error calculation from the GCPs (Ground Control Points) and CPs (Check Points) locations in the data processing, the values are much higher than expected for the survey settings (approximately 5 cm for both GCPs and CPs). I would like to understand how the error estimation is calculated in the software to fully comprehend the evaluation procedure.
During the data processing, I followed the standard workflow steps to obtain both the DTM and the orthophoto. In particular, I have considered:

GCPs and CPs equally distributed all over the area;
Unchecked all images in the reference pane in order to force Metashape to only use our GCPs (not the camera locations);
GPS elevation values come from a Leica device with an accuracy of approx. 1.0 cm (I used 1.25 cm as a safe side in the error estimation);

Here are the specifics of my setup and survey:
UAV: DJI Mavic 2 Pro
Camera: Hasselblad L1D-20c
Altitude: 25 m AGL (Ground Sampling Distance = 7.27 mm/px)
Flight Speed: approx 4.0 m/s
Number of Flights: 2 (total of 697 images)
Overlap (Front/Side): 70% - 75%
GCPs: Obtained using a Leica GS15
Despite these settings, the error values are significantly higher. Could someone explain the process Metashape uses to calculate these errors? Are there common pitfalls or settings I might be overlooking that could lead to higher error rates?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Edoardo, do have you optimized the alignment after placing GCPs?
Try several approaches:

use all calibration parameter for optimization;
use all calibration parameters + Fit Additional Corrections option;
if the camera has a rolling shutter, enable corresponding option in Camera Calibration window and optimize the alignment.


@dead_PyKto: Thank you for your response. After placing the GCPs, I optimized the alignment without including the CPs at this stage. I will try options 2 and 3. I appreciate your time and assistance.
